# If LINQ query retruns IEnumerable<int> does it matter if I add AsNoTracking()?

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

If LINQ query retruns IEnumerable does it matter if I add AsNoTracking()?

For instance:

```
return _context.People
     .Include(person => person.Cars)
     .AsNoTracking()
     .SelectMany(person => person.Cars)
     .Select(car => car.Id)
     .ToImmutableHashSet();
```

Does adding `.AsNoTracking()` actually changes anything, I don't think EF would track just ints.

Comment: EF cannot know what comes after your call of `AsNoTracking`, so that method is just applied to what you pass(persons which are no longer tracked). Of course it has no relevance for your selected car-id's.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `AsNoTracking()` affects an entire query, it doesn't matter where it's placed. You can verify that by checking `_context.People.Local` and the other Local collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "just ints". EF Core tracks only *entity* instances, returned either directly or as part of a non entity class projection. Everything else is not tracked, so yes, `AsNoTracking` is not needed (it is simply ignored for such type of queries).

The same btw applies to `Include` - they have effect only for queries returning entity instances to load (populate) their navigation properties. They are also ignored for non entity returning queries.

So you sample query should be simply

```cs
return _context.People
    .SelectMany(person => person.Cars)
    .Select(car => car.Id)
    .ToImmutableHashSet();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter It actually does ignore them. Projection queries are special case, the equivalent of SQL `SELECT Col1, Col2, ...` rather than `SELECT *`, or db view vs db table if you prefer. `Include` affects the object materialization (again, only when returning full entity class instances), not the query joins and columns in the select. This btw is quite old concept originating from "classic" EF6. Tracking affects only query *materialization* (creation/updating) entity instances. All other class instances (anonymous, typed, primitive) in the query result are not tracked regardless of the opt.